# iPad jQuery menu, clicking anywhere outside to hide dropdown

Tags: jquery, ipad

If you visit this webpage from iPad http://morsapera.com/rb/HTML-Files/home.html and click on any menu item it shows dropdown.

I want the dropdown to hide when a user clicks anywhere outside the menu. I have managed to do it partially and now if you click on image just below menu it hides the dropdown but it still remains when you click anywhere in the header.

Answer (score 2):

```
    jQuery(document).on('touchstart', function(event) {
        if ( !jQuery(event.target).closest("#navi ul").length) {
            jQuery("#navi ul").fadeOut();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled like years now with pure CSS dropdown menus on touch devices. But then, a few days ago I found [this wonderful jQuery plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/doubletaptogo-responsive-and-touch-friendly-dropdown-navigation).

I'd really recommend removing your old ideas, include this script to your project and get lucky with just one line of code :)

```
$('#navi li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();
```

**EDIT**
Unfortunately jsFiddle is either down or maintained (patch tuesday). I tested the jQuery plugin with up to 4 levels and it works perfect!!!!

Here is a quite large bunch of code, but as I said, jsFiddle doesn't work at the moment.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="doubletaptogo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { console.log('ready'); $('li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();});
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        body * {
            display:block;
        }
        ul li {
            width:200px;
            height:100px;

            float:left;
            position:relative;

            background-color:red;
        }
        ul li ul {
            top:100px;
            left:0px;
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
        }
        ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
        ul li ul li {
            position:relative;
            background-color:green;
        }
        ul li ul li ul {
            top:0px;
            left:200px;
            width:10000px;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li {
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li ul {
            top:100px;
            left:0px;
            width:200px;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li ul li {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        ul li ul li ul li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            test 1
        </li>
        <li>
            test 1
            <ul>
                <li>
                    test 2.1
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            test 2.1
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            test 3.2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    test 2.2
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            test 3.1
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            test 3.2
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    test 3.1
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    test 3.2
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd use it but I need 3 level menu while this plugin is only 2 level. Thanks for suggestion. I did looked into this one.

Comment: Please review and test my code. It works and I tested it up to 4 levels

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your click handler for menu:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Then put this in your init function or just anywhere I suppose:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
  //REMOVE CLASS THAT MAKES MENU SHOW OR WHATEVER
});
```